# How to compile, build, run ng2-bootstrap-development?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, ng2-bootstrap

[ng2-bootstrap-development](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap) doesn't compile for me. I see angular-cli in there, but when I run `ng serve` I get `You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command.` What am I missing?

Comment: You have to specify the path. Would be easier if you show us the path to your project. And by the way - it's `ng serve` not `ng-serve`.

Comment: Oops, typo. Edited. Path is: /Users/bradley/Work/ng2-bootstrap-development

Comment: Hold on, I've downloaded it and it doesn't work for me either. I will try do fix it and let you know.

Comment: did you try changing to the `/src/` directory and running `ng serve` from there?

Comment: I get the same result if I try that.

Comment: you have to run ng serve on your root project.  if you created your app with ng new someAppName than you need to run ng serve from inside someAppName directory

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you want to use it together with `angular-cli` you have to make following steps:

```
npm i -g angular-cli
ng new my-app
cd my-app
ng serve
```

#### Adding ng2-bootstrap

Now Install ng2-bootstrap and bootstrap

```
npm install ng2-bootstrap bootstrap --save
```

Open `src/app/app.module.ts` and add

```
import { AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
...

@NgModule({
...
 imports: [AlertModule.forRoot(), ... ],
 ... 
})
```

Now open `angular-cli.json` and insert a new entry into the styles array

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

Now open `src/app/app.component.html` and add

```
<alert type="success">hello</alert>
```

**Source**:

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md

Comment: Thanks. But I wasn't trying to import it into a project, I was trying to build the component library, for development.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to run and serve ng2-bootstrap demos, with virtualenv. Courtesy of my trusty colleague.

```
cd ~
mkdir test
cd test
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install nodeenv
nodeenv -p

git clone https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap.git
cd ng2-bootstrap

npm install -g angular-cli
npm install
npm run demo.serve
```